# knitr: not print leading zeros

Tags: r, printing, knitr

I use knitr to integrate R into LaTeX, where decimals starting with zero should be printed without the zero. For example

```
0.05 =>  .05
0.5  =>  .5
1.5  => 1.5
```

Is there an easy way to get knitr to do this inline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could redefine the inline hook to remove the 0 when your output is numeric and is between -1 and 1.

````
---
output:  pdf_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(inline =
  function (x) {
      if (is.numeric(x)) {
          x = round(x, getOption("digits"))
          if (x < 1 & x > -1) {
            x = sub("0\\.","\\.",as.character(x)) 
          }

      }
      paste(as.character(x), collapse = ", ")
      }
  )
```


Sepal and Petal lengths (r = `r cor(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length)`) ; 
Sepal length and width (r = `r cor(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)`)
````